# Need to add a delay on mouse-out to this code

Tags: javascript, popup, drupal-6

This is some javascript for a drupal 6.x module called "Views Popup".
https://drupal.org/project/views_popup

I can't seem to set a delay on the popup when the mouse moves off the link that triggers the popup. I have the title, teaser text and a more link in the popup and users need to be able to move the mouse off the link (image) in order to click on the "read more" link. I've tried adjusting all the settings in the code below, but none seem to relate to this. I'm not a coder, but I think something needs to be added to make this work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
var popup_time = 0;
var popup_elem = 0;
var popup_show_timer = 0;
var popup_reset_timer = 0;

$(function() {
  popup_reset();

  $(".views-popup").appendTo("body");
});

Drupal.behaviors.viewsPopup = function(context) {
  $(".views-popup-row").mouseover(function() {
      popup_show(this);
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
      popup_hide(this);
    })
    .mousemove(function(e) {
      popup_move(this,e);
    });
}

function popup_move(me,evt){
  var e, top, left;

  if (Drupal.settings.views_popup.follow_mouse){
    left = evt.pageX + 15;
    top = evt.pageY;

    $("#views-popup-" + $(me).attr("id")).css({
      left: left + 'px',
      top: top + 'px'
    });
  }
}


function popup_show(me) {
  var p, e, top, left, pos ;

  var x = $(me).attr("id");

  e = $("#views-popup-" + $(me).attr("id"));
  if (e == popup_elem) {
    return ; // already handled
  }

  if (! Drupal.settings.views_popup.follow_mouse){
    pos  = $(me).offset();
    left = 20 + pos.left - $(document).scrollLeft();
    top  =  2 + pos.top + $(me).outerHeight() - $(document).scrollTop();
    $(e).css({
      left: left + 'px',
      top:  top  + 'px'
    });
  }

  popup_clear_show_timer();

  if (popup_elem) {
    popup_elem.hide();
    popup_time = 500 ;
  }
  popup_elem = e;
  if ( popup_time == 0 ) {
    popup_show_now();
  } else {
    popup_show_timer = setTimeout("popup_show_now();",popup_time);
  }
}


function popup_show_now() {
  popup_show_timer = 0 ;

  if(popup_elem) {
    popup_elem.show();
    clearTimeout(popup_reset_timer);
    popup_time = 0;
  }
}

function popup_clear_show_timer(){
  if (popup_show_timer) {
    clearTimeout(popup_show_timer);
    popup_show_timer = 0;
  }
}

function popup_hide(me) {
  e = $("#views-popup-" + $(me).attr("id"));

  popup_clear_show_timer();
  clearTimeout(popup_reset_timer);

  e.hide();
  if(e == popup_elem) {
    popup_elem = 2;
  }
  popup_reset_timer = setTimeout('popup_reset()',Drupal.settings.views_popup.reset_time);
}

function popup_reset(){
  popup_time = Drupal.settings.views_popup.popup_delay;
}
```

Comment: You're over complicating this. Remove a bunch of this code, and write something that: A) displays the hover when it's on the link, B) hides the hover when you're not on the link. Once you've got that working, make it so you call those functions with the onMouseOver, onMouseOut events...now when that's working, call another function that calls your onMouseOver function with a delay timer. Now your code works.

Comment: Thanks, Blake. I didn't write the code above. It's from a Drupal 6x module. I don't think I should remove a bunch of the code above code for a couple reasons: 1) I might break something else with the module; 2) I'm not a coder and have no idea what I'm doing! It seems like adding some sort of timed delay to the mouseout function here would do the trick:   .mouseout(function() {
      popup_hide(this);
    })

Comment: see answer, good luck! it appears that the setTimeouts that are in the plugin put the functions in quotes -- that turns them into strings. If you added those, remove the quotes and the parenthesis. The parenthesis initiates the call, a lack of parenthesis just passes a reference to the function itself to be called later.

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming the above code works how you want -- and that you want to set a delay for the popup to hide, what you can do is call javascript's `setTimeout(function, delay)` function, which initiates a callback after `delay` milliseconds.

```
function popup_hide(me) {
  e = $("#views-popup-" + $(me).attr("id"));

  popup_clear_show_timer();
  clearTimeout(popup_reset_timer);

  var delay = 1000; // ms
  setTimeout(e.hide, delay); // <------- here

  if(e == popup_elem) {
    popup_elem = 2;
  }
  popup_reset_timer = setTimeout('popup_reset()',Drupal.settings.views_popup.reset_time);
}
```

This will call e.hide (the function) after 1 second has passed.

Comment: Thanks, Blake! I copied the two new lines of code from your answer above (without the quotes) "var delay = 1000; // ms" then added the next line (again w/out quotes) "setTimeout(e.hide, delay); // 5000" (for a 5 sec delay), pasted it into the js file, uploaded, emptied caches, and it didn't work. :-( Sorry to be such a bother with this. Do you have any other ideas or suggestions. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I'm not a coder, but both of these seem like viable options, but neither work. :-( Maybe this module just can't do this. Thanks again!